# Hot network questions -sized Magento logo doesn't look so good

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design

This has been bothering me for a very long time:

[image]

As you can clearly see here, the header-sized and favicon-sized logos look fine with a clear white border between the hexagon and the letter M, but the Hot Questions page -sized logo looks kinda half-assed and blurry around the edges. I'd like to kindly ask the responsible persons to make the white border as prominent as on the other sizes, please. Thank you for your time.

The resource url is this: http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/magento/img/icon-32.png

And it looks like it has been updated!

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. What do you call the Hot Questions page ?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BSDUK.png)

Comment: oh ok, I reckon you should add that to your question. It's the Hot Network Questions block you're referring to

Comment: No, if you click the highlighted text, you can get to the page with all the currently hot questions, and there it was not looking great. You can also get there by middle-clicking StackExchange logo (to the left from your notification counter at the top of each page). But now it's fixed.